# how to start a function automatically on the system startup in java deployed on Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, servletcontextlistener

I have a java web application deployed on Apache tomcat.In my application there is a function that is continuously reading the data from database.As per my need this should never be stopped.Now my concern is suppose that the system restarts ..In this case i want my that function to be called automatically without any intervention from anywhere..but i have o idea how to achieve it..

I have googled about ServletContextListener but i am not getting how to use it in my case..

Any suggestion to solve the above issue will be heartedly welcomed..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write an implementation of ServletContextListener (org.myapp.Startup.java):

```
public class Startup implements ServletContextListener
{
    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {}

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        // Do your startup work here
    }

}
```

And add it to your web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.myapp.Startup</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: Thank u sir for ur response .I have one doubt, does restarting the system automatically start the function called in contextInitialized

Comment: If your application deploys when the system starts, then yes.

Comment: My application is deployed on Apache tomcat and apache tomcat starts automatically on System reboot..Now in this case will be function called in contextInitialized will execute or not.

Comment: Yes... in fact, the application will not be available for users until this is done executing.

Comment: Sir does setting up the package org.myapp.Startup.java is mandatory ?

Comment: You can call your package and class whatever you like, just be sure to specify the full-qualified-name in the web.xml listener entry